# How to show automatically the details in alert?

Tags: javafx, textarea, alert

I created a Alert with the type INFORMATION. Then i created a TextArea and add to the alert with a GridPane. Now my question is how can i show automatically the details of the alert?

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("TODO Liste");
    alert.setContentText("Alle TODO's in der Liste:");
    alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    GridPane content = new GridPane();
    content.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    content.add(textArea, 0, 0);

    alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(content);
    alert.showAndWait();
```

**EDIT:**

ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: to see the TextArea i need to click on the "show details" otherwise it doesn't show

Comment: You should have a lock at the quite good JavaFX tutorial @ Code Makery - especially the [JavaFX Dialog] (http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the **expandable**Content and not the **content**! So change the line you're setting the content of the `Alert` to:

```
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(content);
```